# How to download complete appcombat lib v7 with res?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to download complete appcombat lib v7.Plz give me a link where I get this complete lib . **I does not want to use dependencies method**
Sorry for English mistakes
Thank you (:

**Edited **
I Want to download library online not using ide

Comment: are u using android-studio or eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get your library from here

https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat/tree/master/libs

- download project and get library from that project and add it to your project

Comment: This lib is not have complete fuction and widget.And res ?

Comment: @user76814, how could i know which functionality you want.. you mention about library only..